# Bulk sending using DocuSign REST API V2

Tags: docusignapi

For bulk sending I followed the steps mentioned in DocuSign user guide (Reference: https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-advanced-sending-using-the-bulk-recipient-feature). However I would like to implement the same using REST API. Please suggest how to go about it. Any reference link would really be helpful.
In my application I am using REST API V2.

Answer (score 2):

After using POST /accounts/[accountnumber]/envelopes to create a draft envelope, use the PUT /accounts/[accountnumber]/envelopes/[envelopeID]/recipients/[recipientID]/bulk_recipients to upload your csv file.

Or more specifically, you don't send the file, you send the contents.  You Content-Type for the PUT is text/csv.  The body of the put would be the csv contents just like you'd be viewing them in notepad.

After the put, use the envelopes POST again to change the status to "sent" and it's done.

The response from the final call provides a bulk send batch ID that can be used for checking status.

Answer (score 1):

Information on utilizing bulk send with the DocuSign REST API can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/using-bulk-send-in-rest.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____40)

Comment: I tried using this API [link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/using-bulk-send-in-rest.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____40). But couldn't add the CSV file in a draft envelope in docusign. Also checked in API explorer the way to upload CSV file. [link](http://iodocs.docusign.com/) Please suggest where I am going wrong.